# У меня проблемы с тем как добраться до нужного атрибута во время парсинга на node.js c xml

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const axios = require('axios');
const parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

const wsdlEndpoint = 'somelink';
const soapRequest = `
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:api="http://api.csr.mind.com" xmlns:open="http://api.csr.mind.com/openSession">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <api:openSession>
                <open:request>
                    <open:session key="12" />
                    <open:user name="name" password="password"/>
                </open:request>
            </api:openSession>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
`;
axios.post(wsdlEndpoint, soapRequest, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
        'SOAPAction': 'somelink',
    },
})
    .then(response => {
        const soapResponse = response.data;
        console.log('SOAP Response:', soapResponse);
        
        parseString(soapResponse, { explicitArray: false, ignoreAttrs: true }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error parsing SOAP response:', err);
            } else {
                const sessionID = result['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body']['ns1:openSessionReturn']['ns88:response']['ns88:session'][0]['$']['id'];
                console.log('Session ID:', sessionID);
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error making SOAP request:', error);
    });
```

Вот сам ответ, почему то не могу взять этот id `<ns88:session id="123456789"/>`

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:openSessionReturn xmlns:ns1="http://api.com">
         <ns88:response xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="open.xsd" 
           xmlns:ns88="http://api.csr.mind.com/openSession">
            <ns88:session id="1776470983"/>
         </ns88:response>
      </ns1:openSessionReturn>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Необходимо мне получить этот атрибут, до него могу добраться, а именно ID Не могу получить.

Comment: по опыту, использование https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap удобнее, чем axios

Answer (score 0):

> не могу взять этот id `<ns88:session id="123456789"/>`

Вот так его можно получить...

```js
const xmlString = `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:openSessionReturn xmlns:ns1="http://api.com">
         <ns88:response xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="open.xsd" 
           xmlns:ns88="http://api.csr.mind.com/openSession">
            <ns88:session id="1776470983"/>
         </ns88:response>
      </ns1:openSessionReturn>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`;
 
const domParser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDOM = domParser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
const o = xmlDOM.querySelector("[id]");
console.log(o.id);
```